# MS Access (64bit) VBA Filecopy problems

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10, 64-bit, file-copying

I bought a new computer that installed office 64bit. I have a database from my previous computer using 32bit. When trying to use the old database, filecopy crashes the program every time. I've tried to research on on how to convert the database to work in 64bit to no luck. Below is what I use to change file names via vba. I searched high and low to find an alternative, but can't seem to find anything. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Dave

```
FileCopy "C:\Users\xxx\Order Book.xls", "C:\Users\xxx\T4 " & Year(Date) & Format(Month(Date), "00") & Format(Day(Date), "00") & ".xls"
```

Comment: Does the database from the old computer open on your new computer?

Answer (score 2):

Open the code editor (VBE), go to menu *Tools, References* and check for any reference marked MISSING. Resolve that.

Then compile the code. Correct as needed. Finally, save.

Your code runs fine here, though it can be reduced to:

```
FileCopy "C:\Users\xxx\Order Book.xls", "C:\Users\xxx\T4 " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xls"
```

Comment: <br/> Nothing in References is missing.<br/>I tried running a code with  the "*" and it bombed too, any thoughts?<br/> """[FileCopy "C:\Users\xxx\Order Book" &"*" & ".xls", "C:\Users\xxx\T4 " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xls"]"""

Comment: Then try a _Compact & Repair_, or rewrite the code piece (no copy-paste).

Comment: Tried and still getting path not found.

Comment: First it crashed, now path not found. That's progress. However, if _path_ or _file_ not found, it isn't there, so double-check.

Comment: Am I missing any reference?   Visual Basic for Applications  Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library  OLE Automation  Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine object  Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library  Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library  Microsoft Internet Controls  Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library  Microsoft Scripting Runtime  FoxitPrevHndleLib  FoxitReader 1.0 Type Library  Nothing Missing!

Comment: If a reference is MISSING, it will clearly be labelled as that.